# How can I refer to all files that are named using two numbers?

Tags: scripts

I want to make a shell script that downloads all files that area named [0-9][0-9].png;

e.g: 00.png 01.png 33.png 91.png etc

```
files = ???????

for file in files
do

curl ftp://server/${file}

done
```

What should I put at files = ???

Answer (score 4):

I'd be highly surprised if the `ftp://server/file` protocol permits wildcards. I suspect you'll have to fetch a list of the available files and iterate over the ones with 2 digits.

However if you want to *generate* the numbers 00 to 99 in bash:

```
for file in {0..9}{0..9}.png; do ...
```

Comment: The FTP `mget` command does in fact allow wildcards. However, it would probably depend on the particular server whether it implements actual REGEXP's like `{0..9}{0..9}.png`.

Answer (score 2):

Use Bash's [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) (using `*`, `?` and `[]`):

```
$ ls
00.png  03.png  06.png  09.png  12.png  15.png  18.png  21.png
01.png  04.png  07.png  10.png  13.png  16.png  19.png
02.png  05.png  08.png  11.png  14.png  17.png  20.png
$ files=([0-9][0-9].png)
$ echo "${files[@]}"
00.png 01.png 02.png 03.png 04.png 05.png 06.png 07.png 08.png 09.png 10.png 11.
png 12.png 13.png 14.png 15.png 16.png 17.png 18.png 19.png 20.png 21.png
```

This, unlike `{0..9}{0..9}.png`, only expands to existing filenames. So you could do:

```
files=([0-9][0-9].png)   # creates an array

for FILE in "${files[@]}"
do
    curl "ftp://server/${FILE}"
done
```

Or, directly:

```
for FILE in [0-9][0-9].png    
do
    curl "ftp://server/${FILE}"
done
```

Comment: My idea was to create a nested for loop for i in seq 0 9 do for j in seq 0 9 do //whatever it takes to do done done, but yours seems a more comprehensive.

Comment: But the OP says he wants to download files. My understanding is that the files that must be downloaded don't exist in the client computer. Is that correct, @Adrian? I don't think filename expansion will work. If there's no file in your computer `[0-9][0-9].png` will expand to nothing. Am I right?

Comment: Eric I think files=([0-9][0-9].png)  this creates something like files="00.png 01.png 02.png etc.... " am I right?

Comment: @EricCarvalho Indeed you're right! I don't know how I missed that even after typing in `curl` twice. I will leave this here in the off-chance that someone wants to continue partially downloaded files or something.

Comment: @AdrianGeorge yes, but only if the files exist locally. (And actually, it creates an array, so that `${files[0]}` is `00.png`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`seq` prints a sequence of numbers. `-w` equalizes width by padding with leading zeroes.

```
files=`seq -w 0 99`

for file in $files
do

curl ftp://server/${file}.png

done
```